# $a_n = n ( \sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{n}} - 1 )$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

i have to show  convergence and the limit.

$a_n = n ( \sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{n}} - 1 )$

So far, i  tryed to used $a^2 - b^2$, and got

$ \frac {1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+1} $

how can i go on?

Comment: What does $1/n$ converge to?  (You really have done all the hard work to solve this problem.)

Comment: 1/n goes to 0, but its in the denominator,so the whole terms goes to infinity?

Comment: No - the denominator is $\sqrt{1+\frac1n} + 1$, and this goes to $\sqrt 1 + 1 = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n = n \left( \sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{n}} - 1 \right)= \frac {1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+1} \to \frac{1}{2}$ for $n\to\infty$ because $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$.